# Why does waiting too long to promote an object from the young generation result in less efficiency?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

Why does waiting too long to promote an object from the young generation lead to inefficiency?

One explanation I have seen said that if you wait too long to promote the young generation, it will become less sparse (i.e. the size of the live set will become larger, viewed as a percentage of total young generation size).

But how does that result in a lower efficiency? Suppose that when the young generation is sparse (say, the live set is 2% of its size), collecting it will take `X` CPU time, and 50 collections over some period `T` will take `50X` CPU time. If instead we wait until it has filled up to 100% of its size (which would also take period `T` to happen), collecting it all at once should take only proportionately longer, i.e. `(100/2)*X=50X` CPU time. So in the end, the total time spent collecting will be the same — whether you're collecting 50 times at 2% occupancy, or collecting once at 100% occupancy. Where's the efficiency benefit of the first approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying.

Most objects in the young generation die and don't get touch by the GC at all (yes, it's actually a *survivor collector*, live objects gets copied and what's left is free memory).

An object surviving several minor collections will probably live long. So copying it again and again would needlessly cost time.

> if instead we wait until it has filled up to 100% of its size

You don't have *this* option. You collect whenever the eden space gets (nearly) full. You do nothing if only 2% of it are used. But...

After the collection, you see that maybe only 2% of the object survived.

*Your mistake is misinterpreting the percentage. This 2% are no threshold, it's the outcome and you have no knob to change it. You can change the eden size and such things, but the effect on the survivor percentage is just indirect.*

Answer (score 1):

One reason is, that each object in the *new generation* will be copied from *eden* to *survivor* and then multiple times between *survivor spaces*. So if you know an Instance will not die young promoting it quickly will reduce the number of copies. If the object is in the old generation it will typically not be copied (only traversed). This not only reduces the number of copy operations but also the need for changing the instance's address in all references.

There is no fragmentation problem with a copying collector in the young generation, so this is not the reason.

It should be mentioned however that it is not trivial to know if a object dies young or not. If you have very short running transactions you can however assume that most objects die quickly so there is no need to keep them in survivor spaces (at all).